# Footer not sticking to the bottom of the page (not fixed)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my footer at the bottom of the page - not fixed. The HTML layout is as follows:

```
<header><!-- content --></header>
<main>
    <div class="margin-center">
      <div class="individual">
          <section class="hours">
          </section>
      </div>
      <div class="stacked">
          <section class="blog">
          </section>
          <section class="pets-seen">
          </section>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
 <!-- footer content -->
</footer>
```

The following is my CSS:

```
footer {
  /* color */
  background-color: #334051;
  color: #fff;

  /* position and size */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height 500px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
```

All aspects of the page are working and display fine except for the footer which displays over the rest of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is what happens, when you use `position: absolute`. You can read up more [here](http://de.learnlayout.com/position.html). Simply remove it and the standard (`static`) should work.

```css
footer {
  /* color */
  background-color: #334051;
  color: #fff;

  /* position and size */
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height 500px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header><!-- content --></header>
<main>
    <div class="margin-center">
      <div class="individual">
          <section class="hours">
          </section>
      </div>
      <div class="stacked">
          <section class="blog">
          </section>
          <section class="pets-seen">
          </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000">
</main>
<footer>
 <!-- footer content -->
 This is the footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Did he really just meant it to be at the bottom as in the last content? If so, no CSS for positioning was needed to be applied at all.

Comment: Well that is what he says, as far as I can tell. Idk, he probably just copy-pasted the code or needed it for something else. The `left: 0;` is also really strange. Maybe he wanted no margin and that was the first thing that worked?